# Looking for alternate ways to create blocks of HTML code in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm not sure how to phrase my question, so I essentially want to be able to do something like this, in ASP.NET MVC 3:

```
@myJsHtmlCustomCode
{
    <div><h1>Title</h1></div>
}
```

where anything in that `myJsHtmlCustomCode` block would be surrounded with some custom JavaScript/HTML code that I wrote.

I know I could use something like `myJsHtmlCustomCode.Begin()` and `myJsHtmlCustomCode.End()` in my code, but that doesn't provide the same formatting structure.

If anyone knows of a similar way to achieve the same objective, and get the automatic outlining/indent formatting, that would be great.

Just for reference, I wanted the the `@myJsHtmlCustomCode` to surround the code with for instance, another `<div id="myTestId" onclick="thisClickEvent"></div>` for the resulting code to look like...

```
<div id="myTestId" onclick="thisClickEvent">    
    <div><h1>Title</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It might help to include a sample of the kind of output you want.  We can't read your mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

You can wrap your code in an object that implements IDisposable, just like you use `@using (Html.BeginForm())`

Your code could be like this:

```
public class MyJsHtmlCustomCode : IDisposable {
    private ViewContext _ctx; 

    public MyJsHtmlCustomCode (HtmlHelper html, /* other params */) {
       _ctx = html.ViewContext;
       /* Write begin tags */
        _ctx.Writer.Write("html => opening tags");        }

    public Dispose() {
        _ctx.Writer.Write("html => closing tags");
    }
}
```

and the extension:

```
public static MyJsHtmlCustomCode BeginMyJsHtmlCustomCode(this HtmlHelper html /* other params */) {
    var result = new MyJsHtmlCustomCode(html);
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
@using(Html.BeginMyMyJsHtmlCustomCode()) {
     <div>This is surrounded by your code </div>
}
```

### Option 2

[You can use Razor Templated Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx):

```
@{
  Func<dynamic, object> b = @<strong>@item</strong>;
}
<span>This sentence is @b("In Bold").</span>
<div>@b(
   @<span>
       @DateTime.Now 
   </span><span>Example of more complex logic
   </span>
)</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for, was going to add more detail, but ended up having a baby over the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

While I must admit I do not completely understand your question, whenever I need to do programatic custom HTML manipulation in .Net MVC 3 I use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Could you achieve your desired result using @section ?

e.g.: in one cshtml, possibly the _Layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// whatever you want
// more whatever you want
@RenderSection("jsCode", false)
// even more whatever you want
</script>
```

Then in your actual view cshtml:

```
@section jsCode{
   <div><h1>Title</h1></div>    
}
```

<del>You could possibly use a partial view for the js bit e.g.</del>